# Filtering data from an APII

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am having a problem filtering data from an API based on their regularPrice. So the error I am having is kinda stupid. This is the error  `Data is not being iterable in the` useLayoutEffect. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you very much. Here is the sandbox link. https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-currying-77y43?file=/src/books.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import URL from '../utilis/URL';
const BookContext = React.createContext();
export default function BooksProvider({ children }) {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [filters, setFilters]= useState({
    regularPrice:"all",
    length:""
   
  })
  
  /*fetching data */ 
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    const result = await response.json();  
    console.log(result)
    setData(result);
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
  },[])

  const updateFilters = e => {
    const type = e.target.type;
    const filter = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    let filterValue;
    if (type === "checkbox") {
      filterValue = e.target.checked;
    } else if (type === "radio") {
      value === "all" ? (filterValue = value) : (filterValue = parseInt(value));
    } else {
      filterValue = value;
    }
    setFilters({ ...filters, [filter]: filterValue });
  };

  /* filtering price books */ 
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let newBooks = [...data].sort((a, b) => a.regularPrice - b.regularPrice);
   
    if (regularPrice !== "all") {
      newBooks = newBooks.filter(item => {
        if (regularPrice === 0) {
          return item.regularPrice <10;
        } else if (regularPrice === 10) {
          return item.regularPrice > 10 && item.regularPrice < 20;
        } else {
          return item.regularPrice > 20;
        }
      });
    }
  }, [filters, data]);

 const { regularPrice } = filters;  
return (
    <BookContext.Provider value={{ data, filters, regularPrice, updateFilters, handleSelectCategory, setCurrentSelectedCategory, currentSelectedCategory }}>
      {children}
    </BookContext.Provider>
  );
}
export {BookContext, BooksProvider}
```

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { BookContext } from '../../context/books'

const Filters = () => {
    const {filters:{regularPrice, updateFilters}}= useContext(BookContext)
    return (
        <div>
              <p>Regular Price</p>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="regularPrice"
              id="all"
              value="all"
              checked={regularPrice === "all"}
              onChange={updateFilters}
            />
            all
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="regularPrice"
              value="0"
              checked={regularPrice === 0}
              onChange={updateFilters}
            />
            $0 - $10
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="regularPrice"
              value="10"
              checked={regularPrice === 10}
              onChange={updateFilters}
            />
            $10 - $20
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="regularPrice"
              value="20"
              checked={regularPrice === 20}
              onChange={updateFilters}
            />
            Over $20
          </label>
       
        </div>
    )
}

export default Filters
```

Parent

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import './Home.css'
import Books from './Books'
import {GiHamburgerMenu} from 'react-icons/gi'
import { BookContext } from "../../context/books";
import Filters from './Filters';
import Responsive from './Responsive'
const Home = () => {
   const {data, handleSelectCategory, currentSelectedCategory } 
   =useContext(BookContext)
   const[isCategoryOpen, setIsCategoryOpen]=useState(false)
  
  function closeCategory(){
    setIsCategoryOpen(false)
  }
   return (
        <div className='books__container' >
            <div className='responsive' >
              <GiHamburgerMenu onClick={()=> 
             setIsCategoryOpen(!isCategoryOpen)}/> 
              {isCategoryOpen ? <Responsive />:null}
            </div>  
            <h1 className='categories'>Categories</h1>
            {Object.keys(data).map((key, index)=>{
            let books = data[key];
            return (              
              <div key={key} onClick={() => handleSelectCategory(key)} 
              className='books__list' >
              {books[0].category}     
              </div>                 
              );})}   
              <Filters />
              <Books category={currentSelectedCategory} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Child

```
import React,{useContext, ReactFragment} from 'react'
import { CartContext } from '../../context/cart';
import HoverBooks from './HoverBooks';
import { useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserContext } from '../../context/user';
const Books = ({category}) => {
const {addToCart }= useContext(CartContext)
const { user } = React.useContext(UserContext);

    return (     
        <div className='books__main'>      
        {category.slice(0, 5).map((book) => {   
          console.log(book)    
          return(
           <React.Fragment key={book.id}>
           <HoverBooks 
           key={book.id}
           {...book}       
           />    
           <div className='book__content'>
            <li className='book__name'>{book.bookName}</li>
             <h4 className='book__prop'>By: {book.by}</h4>
             <h4  className='book__prop'>Narreted by: {book.Narreted || 
           book["Narreted by"]}</h4>
             <h4  className='book__prop'>Length: {book.length || book["Length"]} 
            </h4>
             <h4  className='book__prop'>Release Date: {book.ReleaseDate}</h4>
             <h4  className='book__prop'>Language: {book.Language}</h4>
             <h4  className='book__prop'>Rating: {book.rating}</h4>
           </div>           
           <div className='book__adt'> 
           <h4>Regular Price: {book.RegularPrice}</h4>
           {user.authToken ? (
           
           <button onClick={() => 

              addToCart(book)
           }
           >Add to cart</button>  
           ) : (
            <Link to="/login" className="adt__login">
            Login to buy books
           </Link>
        )}
           </div>
       </React.Fragment>
        )})}
      </div>
     
    )
}
export default Books
```

Comment: The codebox example you linked gives another different errors, "regularPrice is not defined" and "keyEventHandler is not defined".

Comment: @Motoroller mb I forgot to save  try this https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-maxwell-4jjdi

Comment: I printed the content of `data` from console.log and it contains an object `{Arts and Entertainment: Array(5), Biographies Memoirs: Array(5), Business and Careers: Array(5), Children's Audiobooks: Array(5), Computers and Technology: Array(5), …}` Is this what you expected? I'm not so sure but I thought if you apply `sort` action there should be an attribute `regularPrice` in a direct child

Comment: @Motoroller maybe the sort, is not the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make the error gone by converting `result` object by `Object.values` and using it in `setData`.

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    const result = await response.json();
    const resultArray = Object.values(result);

    setCurrentSelectedCategory(resultArray[0]['category']);
    //    setCurrentSelectedCategory(result[Object.keys(result)[0]]);
    setData(resultArray);
  };
```

[image: No errors]

I am not sure how this app filter should work though. If you could illustrate a picture of the complete application I might be able to figure out more (e.g. If you do this by following some kind of tutorial you could point to the URL to that resource, etc).

As I stated in my comment before, it seems that you cannot use result from api response directly. If you see the heroku app's end point in browser the structure is clear.

I also recommend that you avoid using same filenames in the same folder as in your codesandbox sample, such as (`books.js` and `Books.js`), even the operation system allows both to exist.

Comment: I have updated the question. So you see in the Parent component, I am iterating the data from the API. I am passing that data to the Child as props. So the filters are there to filter the books based on the regular price

Comment: So you don't use `category` returned by api at all?

Comment: only in the Parent component and child

Comment: I am afraid I feel a bit confused, have you changed codesandbox example from the last time as well? It used to give an error in the same syntax around `setCurrentSelectedCategory` in `fetchData`

Comment: I have not touched anything

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-wilson-8sn41?file=/src/books.js

Comment: I am sorry if I am misleading, but the error I see in this codesandbox is `regularPrice is not defined`. This is a different error from the one `Data is not being iterable in the...` you put in the first question, isn't it? What I could not get was now in the original codesandbox (`unruffled-currying...`) that error disappears. Do you know if there is a change in the heroku's api response? Or are you coding this api part by yourself as well?

Comment: Just Ctrl+x the attempt of the destructuring book outside ``` const { regularPrice } = filters```  of layout effect, I have updated the question so you can see. Api is mine

Comment: is everything okay with the filter logic at least

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230727/discussion-between-motoroller-and-mura1).